# When I make migrations to Django, all accounts are deleted

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql

When I enter the commands python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate all accounts are deleted from the database. Perhaps the database is simply re-created

UPD. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmq1J.png)

Comment: So you're saying that when you do makemigrations/migrate, add a record in the admin, then run both again, all records are deleted? That doesn't sound accurate according to how they work.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @AleRyp and welcome to stackoverflow.

Usually

```
./manage.py makemigrations
```

does nothing unless you don't have changes in your models.

Instead

```
./manage.py migrate
```

does something only there're new migrations to be applied.

Would be nice to see the output of both commands in your case

Comment: I add screenshot in the question

Comment: What happens if you run `makemigrations` again? Does it create a new migration? Do you ha a custom migration somewhere?

Comment: It says No changes detected. And no, I haven`t custom migration

Comment: So in that case `migrate` should do nothing as well.

Comment: How do you create users?

Comment: For last time I created just super user with command createsuperuser. And with new migration it was deleted, and idk why.